# Standard error for population average treatment effect with nearest neighbor matching

Tags: matching, treatment-effect, weighted-mean

I perform nearest neighbor matching where each treated group $i$ (where $i$ goes from 1 to $I$) has a population $n_i$ and is matched with a non-treated group with population close to $n_i$.

The outcome is $y_i = Y_i/n_i$ for the treated group and $y_i'$ for the not treated group. The sizes $n_i$ vary from 1,000 to 200,000 people, with many more treated groups with smaller populations.

Instead of computing atet = $(1/I) \sum_{i=1}^I (y_i - y_i')$, I would like to compute patet = $[1/(\sum_{i=1}^I n_i)] [\sum_{i=1}^I n_i (y_i - y_i')]$.  Any suggestions of how to compute the standard errors for patet?